# Regex-enabled Linux Find Command Not Returning

Tags: bash, tdd, shunit2

Being someone who is new to bash scripting, I decided to try and unit test my current project from the start. Currently I have a problem with a single line of code. with it I'm trying to search the directory `output_json` for the files that match a regex.

before I show any code here is the directory structure that the script runs in:

full path to working directory:

```
C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\code projects\Replacement Program for Chile Letters\tests\general bash unit tests.
```

directory tree of current working directory:

```
├───general bash unit tests  <--(working dir)
    ├───node_fake_returns
    └───output_json
        ├───email_data-1.json
        ├───email_data-2.json
        ├───email_data-3.json
        ├───variable_data-1.json 
        ├───variable_data-2.json
        └───variable_data-3.json
```

the line that I'm trying to use to return an array containing all the filenames of the `variable_data` files is as follows:

```bash
local contentVars=$(find "./output_json" -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/output_json/variable_data-\d+.json')
```

Here's is the entire function used to unit test just in case I having something else wrong with the unit test. note the assertion function is from shunit2.

```bash
testFileNameCapturing() {

    local contentVars=$(find "./output_json" -regextype posix-extended \
      -regex '.*/output_json/variable_data-\d+.json')
    local emailDataVars=$(find "./output_json" -regextype posix-extended \
      -regex 'variable_data-\d+.json')

    assertTrue "[ $contentVars == './output_json/variable_data-1.json' ]"
}
```

I'm sure this is just a small syntax error, but it really has stalled me for a majority of the day. Any help would be great!

Comment: Someone else had answered about the regex and they seem to have deleted their answer. I agree, there is something strange about the regex. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 parts. On your regex question, and on simplifying your unit test code.

---

**On the regex:**

On the regex, I agree that there is something odd about the implementation of GNU find's handling of regex.

Documentation for the GNU find regex is found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions).

If you use the default GNU find regular expression, you can write this:

```
▶ find ./output_json -regex './output_json/variable_data-[0-9]+\.json'                       
./output_json/variable_data-1.json
./output_json/variable_data-3.json
./output_json/variable_data-2.json
```

Using POSIX-extended, however, I would, like you, expect `\d` to match a digit. It works [here](https://www.regextester.com/99203) for instance.

But in the GNU find posix-extended regex [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax) there is no mention of `\d`, only `[[:digit:]]`.

Thus, this works:

```
▶ find "./output_json" -regextype posix-extended -regex './output_json/variable_data-[[:digit:]]+\.json'
./output_json/variable_data-1.json
./output_json/variable_data-3.json
./output_json/variable_data-2.json
```

---

**On fixing your code:**

I think you should simplify your code and avoid the regex altogether, and just use a glob pattern:

```bash
local contentVars=$(find ./output_json -name "variable_data-[0-9]*.json")
```

This is simpler, easier to understand, and doesn't rely on a GNU extension, thus is more portable.

That's not going to return an array, however, but a newline-separated string, and the assertion you make:

```bash
assertTrue "[ $contentVars == './output_json/variable_data-1.json' ]"
```

should fail. Perhaps try:

```bash
testFileNameCapturing() {
  local contentVars=$(find output_json/ -name "variable_data-[0-9]*.json")

  local expected="output_json/variable_data-1.json
output_json/variable_data-3.json
output_json/variable_data-2.json"

  assertEquals "$expected" "$contentVars"
}

. shunit2
```

Output:

```
testFileNameCapturing

Ran 1 test.

OK
```